# WMI: “File not found” when trying to retrieve “ServerNetworkProtocol” scope for SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wmi

I am trying to get Server Network Protocol (SQL Server) using WMI.

I had written small application:

```
---------------------------C# code--------------------------
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\computerName\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement");
scope.Options.Username = "Administrator";
scope.Options.Password = "Password";
scope.Connect();

var query = new ObjectQuery(@"SELECT * FROM ServerNetworkProtocol");
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
var managementObjectCollection = searcher.Get();
var result = managementObjectCollection.Cast<ManagementObject>().ToList(); //<---- FileNotFoundException
var s = result.First()["ProtocolName"].ToString();
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Protocol name:  {0}", s));
```

And when I run the application, I will receive System.IO.FileNotFoundException. 
I tested the query using WBEMTest Utility and everything is okey (with Administrator credentials).
Later I had written test service and put the same code, and service works correctly without any exceptions.
I suppose the problem related with credentials.

Can anyone explain more detailed what's wrong. What permissions need to run this query (if problem with credentials) and how I can resolve the issue.

I will be appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 0):

just check credential and [change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms182491%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) one line :

```
 ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\computerName\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10");
```

Comment: I have already checked management path (WBEMTest Utility) and the path is correct. Besides if management path is incorrect, the application will throw management exception with Invalid namespace message. Login and password are correct too, because I can connect (scope.Connect()).

Comment: you can check by changing the path

Comment: I have already checked and the path is correct. Besides "..\ComputerManagement10" is sql server 2008 path, for sql server 2005 correct path is "..\ComputerManagement".

Comment: have you tested with `..\ComputerManagement10` ?

Comment: yes, I have installed both Sql Servers (2005 and 2008), so I have both namespaces. I have tested with ..\ComputerManagement10 - and error is the same.